# Another case with Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #2) in ApiService.login

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines, illegalargumentexception

I'm stuck at Exception that appears in the title. I checked similar topics, but they were specific cases that didn't apply to my situation. Below you could see my models, retrofit setup and its usage. I tried removing Body Class, Response Class, just to check if they are culprits, but unfortunately those weren't the case. Maybe someone will be able to figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #2)
        for method ApiService.login
        at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:52)
        at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:42)
        at retrofit2.Utils.parameterError(Utils.java:61)
        at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.parseParameter(RequestFactory.java:311)
        at retrofit2.RequestFactory$Builder.build(RequestFactory.java:182)
        at retrofit2.RequestFactory.parseAnnotations(RequestFactory.java:65)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:25)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:168)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:147)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
        at $Proxy1.login(Unknown Source)
        at com.rudearts.cyber2020.services.NetworkService$login$1.invokeSuspend(NetworkService.kt:17)
        at com.rudearts.cyber2020.services.NetworkService$login$1.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SafeFlow.collect(Builders.kt:56)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowOperatorImpl.flowCollect(ChannelFlow.kt:144)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowOperator.collectTo$suspendImpl(ChannelFlow.kt:111)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlowOperator.collectTo(Unknown Source:0)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.ChannelFlow$collectToFun$1.invokeSuspend(ChannelFlow.kt:33)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:738)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

Models:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class LoginRequest(
    @SerializedName("pin")  val pin:String,
    @SerializedName("pushId") val pushId:String)
```

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class UserJson (

    @SerializedName("id") val id:Long,
    @SerializedName("name") val name:String?,
    @SerializedName("access_rights") val accessRights:String?)
```

Retrofit Builder

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

object RetrofitBuilder {

    private const val BASE_URL = "<url>"

    private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()

    private fun getRetrofit(): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build()
    }

    val apiService: ApiService = getRetrofit().create(ApiService::class.java)
}
```

```
import com.rudearts.cyber2020.model.LoginRequest
import com.rudearts.cyber2020.model.UserJson
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.http.Body
import retrofit2.http.Headers
import retrofit2.http.POST

interface ApiService {

    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("login.php")
    suspend fun login(@Body request: LoginRequest):Response<UserJson>

}
```

Usage in other class:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flow
import java.util.*

class NetworkService {

    private val repoService by lazy { RepoService.instance }
    private val apiService = RetrofitBuilder.apiService

    fun login(pin:String, token:String): Flow<NetworkResult<Boolean>> = flow {
        emit(Loading)
        try {
            val userJson = apiService.login(LoginRequest(pin,token)).body()
            userJson?.let {
                val user =
                    User(userJson.id, userJson.name ?: "", emptyList(), userJson.accessRights ?: "")
                repoService.user = user
            }

            emit(NetworkSuccess(userJson != null))
        } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
            emit(NetworkError(throwable))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the stack-trace of exception you are getting??

Comment: Also check if you are using an older version of okhttp / retrofit as you are using suspend function it requires the latest version of both libraries.

Comment: Hey @TaranmeetSingh, I added full stack trace

Comment: I updated libraries and it works... man what a rookie mistake. Thanks @TaranmeetSingh for pointing this out. If you make it as an answer, I will mark it as correct :)

Comment: kindly do the needfull :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that you are using an older version of  okhttp / retrofit as you are using suspend function it requires the latest version of both libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Try call the function like this

```
fun login(LoginRequest(pin,token))
```

instead of this

```
fun login(pin:String, token:String)
```

the exception says the error is on the second parameter

Comment: Unfortunately, I even tried to remove this parameter completely, but the error just changes to: "No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1) in ApiService.login"

Comment: So instead of passing LoginRequest(pin,token) try do this: val request = LoginRequest(pin,token) and then pass this variable like apiService.login(request).body()

Comment: Thanks @cryptex, but in comment for post above I mentioned that library update was all I needed - problem solved